# Is there an atoi implementation for C#

Tags: c#, atoi

I have a file with numbers saved as strings.  I am looking to load this data as a char[] then convert this array to an integer value.  I have several values to load and am trying to avoid the overhead of creating thousands of temp strings..

Answer (score 9):

Yup

```
int.Parse(string)
```

If you absolutely must convert the strings to character arrays (not sure why), you can use:

```
int.Parse(new string(myCharArray));
```

On a further note...

> I am looking to load this data as a char[] then convert this array to an integer value.

Is there a particular reason to use a `char[]` instead of just reading strings from the file?  You will need a `string` to convert to an `int` anyway (using the standard conversion methods), so it seems like a wasted step.

> I have several values to load and am trying to avoid the overhead of creating thousands of temp strings..

You should only need to create one string for each string you read from the file.  I don't know what other processing is involved here, but reading a string from the file and then converting to an `int` will not create needless temporaries.

If you are performing a large/unknown number of string concatenations then you should use a  `StringBuilder` to build your input as it acts as a mutable string under the covers (initialize it to a large enough size when creating it as well).  Even still, it will (should) take *far* longer to read the data from disk then it will take to create these strings.

Comment: There is a cost to creating strings in .net, I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: And it's incredibly minimal. If you really needed to, you could always construct a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) and insert each char manually.

Comment: @AaronFischer: There is a cost to creating everything.  Have you performed any measurements?  Have you shown that reading a string from a file is inducing a bottleneck in your application?  Why do you believe reading a char array to be extremely less expensive than reading a string?  I would recommend taking the simple path first before introducing what may be needless and ineffective optimizations.

Comment: If you're that much worried about cost, you should stick to C. .NET has way more overhead than just the cost of creating strings.

Comment: @Aaron Fischer: The costs of creating a string are ridiculous small compared with accessing files on a hard drive.

Comment: @ed I have taken the simple path first, There was to much memory usage and I am trying to get whatever perf gain I can.  char is a value type and I can recycle the char[] between reads.

Answer (score 4):

basically

```
 public static int StringToInt( char[] ch )
        {
            int length = ch.Length;
            int i = 0;
            int lastNumber = 0;
            int returnNumber = 0;
            bool numberNegative = false;
            int startPoint = 0;

            if ( ch[ 0 ] == '-' )
            {
                numberNegative = true;
                startPoint = 1;
            }

            for ( i = startPoint; i < length; i++ )
            {
                if ( ch[ i ] == ' ' )
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( ( ch[ i ] >= '0' ) && ch[ i ] <= '9' )
                    {
                        returnNumber = ch[ i ] - '0';
                        if ( i > 0 )
                            lastNumber = lastNumber * 10;
                        lastNumber = lastNumber + returnNumber;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ( numberNegative )
                lastNumber = -1 * lastNumber;

            return lastNumber;
        }
```

Which is from http://www.csharptricks.com/blog/2006/09/string-to-integer-in-c-net.html with the string replaced with char[]

Answer (score 3):

here is also a possible implementation of atoi()

```
int atoi(const char *s)
{
    int n=0, neg=0;
    while (isspace(*s)) s++;
    switch (*s) {
        case '-': neg=1;
        case '+': s++;
    }
    /* Compute n as a negative number to avoid overflow on INT_MIN */
    while (isdigit(*s))
        n = 10*n - (*s++ - '0');
    return neg ? n : -n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of ways:

- `Convert.ToInt32` *<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32.aspx)</sup>*
- `int.Parse` *<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)</sup>*

Although, these methods deal with `string` objects, not `char[]`. In C#, most of the time, you don't deal with `char[]` like you do in C because of the built-in `string` type *<sup>[[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)</sup>*.

Comment: Those functions take a string not a char[]

Comment: @AaronFischer: Why do you require a `char[]` in the first place?

Comment: There's also the problem that the atoi() function allows the string to "contain additional characters after those that form the integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior of this function."

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this question while searching a real `c#` equivalent of `atoi`.
While the original inqirer was satisfied with `int.Parse()`, `atoi` does a lot more than this as @Matt pointed out.

For that reason, I fixed @Alexandre R's code, transferred it to `C#` and unit tested it. Hope it will help someone in future when looking for a real `C#` equivalent of `C/C++`'s `atoi`:

```
public int atoi(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) return 0;
    int n = 0, neg = 0, i = 0;
    while (s[i] == ' ') i++;
    switch (s[i])
    {
        case '-':
            neg = 1; i++;
            break;
        case '+':
            i++;
            break;
    }
    while (char.IsDigit(s[i])) n = 10 * n - (s[i++] - '0');
    return neg == 1 ? n : -n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. My answer might be useful for people working with .NET Core 2.1 (shipped May 30, 2018) or later or .NET 5.0 or later.

You can minimize memory allocations by using a [`ReadOnlySpan<char>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.ReadOnlySpan%25601)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-6.0).

Either read the whole file into a single string with:

```cs
string s = File.ReadAllText("path");
```

... or read the lines and enumerate them with:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines("path");
foreach (string s in lines) {
    //TODO: process the lines
}
```

Then determine the start and length of the spans that make up numbers.

```cs
int start = ...;
int length = ...;
```

... and create a span:

```cs
// This does not allocate heap memory, as the ReadOnlySpan is a ref struct.
// It is a safe reference into the original string.
ReadOnlySpan<char> span = s.AsSpan(start, length);
```

Now you can parse the number:

```cs
if (Int32.TryParse(span, out int result)) {
    //TODO: process result
} else {
    //TODO: handle error
}
```

It uses this overload of [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Int32.TryParse)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-6.0):

```cs
public static bool TryParse(ReadOnlySpan<char> s, out Int32 result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char c = '1';
int i = Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString(), 10); /*base 10 conversion*/
```

Comment: Please add some additional information to your answer. Read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That just converts a single digit to int (digit of type char) - look at the specification of atoi, atoi does much more than that: [specification of atoi function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)