# how to convert char to int

Tags: c, char, int

I'm trying to write a short program were:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
char=a,b,c;
printf("please place 3 numbers:\n");
scanf("%c%c%c", &a,&b,&c);
}
```

The exercise I'm trying to solve is how to change the char to int so if I write in a the number 3, I will get the number 3 Printed.
at this point I'm only getting the value.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is this C#, seriously?

Comment: If your question is about printing variables, you should post code that actually *prints variables*.

Comment: char=a,b,c? type=varname?

Comment: char=a,b,c is not allowed in C programming. Its a syntax error. It should be defined as char a,b,c; and main function return type is int.

EDIT : oh! i am sorry, somebody posted this already..:(

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends somewhat on what you can assume about the character set. If it's something like ASCII (or really, any character set that includes the digits in sequential order), you just need to offset the character value by the value of the character `0`:

```
int aValue = a - '0';
```

I'm sure that C# provides better ways to do what you're trying to do, though. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657836/is-there-an-atoi-implementation-for-c-sharp) for some examples of converting strings to integer values.

Comment: for digits, `a - '0'` is guaranteed to return the expected value since the C standard guarantees it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your syntax need some checking

You should know that you declare a variable this way (a char in this example):

```
char a;
```

If you want to declare multiple variables of the same type in a row you do :

```
char a, b, c;
```

If you want to assign a value to a declared variable :

```
a = '3';
```

Now to print a char using printf (man printf is a must read, more infos are in coreutils) :

```
printf("%c", a);
```

If you want to get the char from the command line, I recommand you to use `getchar()` (man getchar) instead of `scanf` because if suits better what you are trying to achieve and doesn't require you to use a syntax in `scanf` that I am sure you don't fully understand yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incredibly light on details, so here are several options:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a,b,c;
    printf("please place 3 numbers:\n");
    scanf("%c%c%c", &a,&b,&c);

    printf("Printing ints (auto-promotion): %d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
    printf("Printing ints (explicit-promotion): %d %d %d\n", (int)a, (int)b, (int)c);
    printf("Printing digits: %d %d %d\n", a-0x30, b-0x30, c-0x30);
    return 0;
}
```

If the input is `123`, 
I expect the output to be:

```
Printing ints (auto-promotion): 49 50 51
Printing ints (explicit-promotion): 49 50 51
Printing digits: 1 2 3
```

---

Some things I fixed along the way.

- `main` should return an `int`, not be void.
- `char=a,b,c;` is a syntax error.  You meant `char a,b,c;`
- added a `return 0;` at the end of `main`.

Comment: It is preferably not to use `0x30` for this purpose. The C standard does not require C implementations to use ASCII, and, even if an implementation does, the use of a numeric code without explanation is cryptic. One can write `a-'0'` instead, and this is both portable and clear. (The C standard requires that the digit characters be consecutive and ascending.)

Answer (score 0):

You question is not quite understandable. Still I'll try to help. I think that what you want is to store an integer value in the char variable. You can do so by using the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char a,b,c;
printf("Enter three numbers:\n");
scanf(" %c %c %c",&a,&b,&c);       //notice the spaces between %c
}
```

Or if you want to enter a character and print its ASCII value, you can use the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
char a,b,c;
printf("Enter three characters:\n");
scanf(" %c %c %c",&a,&b,&c);
printf("Entered values: %d %d %d",a,b,c);
getch();
}
```